# sending tx with fee/vsize < 1 satoshi

Tags: transaction-fees

is it possible to send tx with fee smaller than 1 satoshi per vbyte?
e.g. vsize is 200 bytes, fee is 100 satoshis

do all nodes accept such transactions?
if not, what nodes do?

PS We're not talking about confirmation.
I just wanna know if nodes would accept it into their mempool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unmodified Bitcoin Core releases from 2017  to date will accept such a transactions to their mempool, relay them, or mine them.

Before 2017 there existed rules that in some cases permitted relay of transactions with lower or no fee at all, though these had been deprecated and default off for several years earlier.

Anyone is of course free to run software that implements their own policy.